# Content export from Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, migration, content-manager

I need to import all the content of a publication from Tridion 2011 and consume in java application. I want to dump all the content in my local repository for one time. I also want to import all assets and maintain the internal reference.

What is the best approach?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Tridion is a web content management system. If you dump everything "one time" into a different repository, you won't be able to use Tridion to content-manage it, will you? That sounds rather self-defeating, but that notwithstanding, Tridion offers many good ways to export its data. For example, the core service API will allow you to read the content and store it wherever you like.

When you say you want to maintain the internal reference, I'm not sure what you mean, but couldn't you just store the value of it somewhere?